# Register GitLab runner without https

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

My GitLab-Repository is only accessible via SSH for my Server. https is blocked.
How can I register a GitLab Runner anway?

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed 
runner status couldn't execute POST against https://MY_URL/api/v4/runners: Post https://MY_URL/api/v4/runners: dial tcp: lookup MY_URL.com: no such host
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Server: Win 10 + Powershell; 
GitLab Repo: GitLab Community Edition 11.10.4